# Extract URL fragment using jquery

Tags: javascript

I've got a URL like this:

```
http://www.foo.bar/234234234
```

I need to grab the Id after `/`, so in this case `234234234`

How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Get a [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) after the [last index of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) `/`.

```
var url = 'http://www.site.com/234234234';
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
alert(id); // 234234234
```

It's just basic JavaScript, no jQuery involved.

Comment: This works great! But what if there is url-stuff on the right side of the url?

Comment: I don't think that this answer cover all possible cases. Because as Tom mentioned above, there could be situation the second part will have some hash, or parameters and then you get what you don't want. E.g. "http://www.example.com/234234234?lang=en" or "http://www.example.com/234234234#tab-id" etc..

Comment: @LubosK: I was just answering within the context of the question. Simply ask/search a new question if you want a more tailored answer to it. Or simply research how exactly to split an URL on `?` and `#` (and `;`) characters and then take the 1st part of it. You don't know if the OP already did this beforehand and omitted it for brevity.

Comment: @BalusC: okay, sure, I fully agree with you. But I just wanted to point out of possible failures/cases for future readers.

Answer (score 58):

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 15):

```
var full_url = document.URL; // Get current url
var url_array = full_url.split('/') // Split the string into an array with / as separator
var last_segment = url_array[url_array.length-1];  // Get the last part of the array (-1)
alert( last_segment ); // Alert last segment
```

Comment: Thanks. Semicolon missing in 2nd line

Answer (score 8):

```
var url = "http://www.site.com/234234234"
var stuff = url.split('/');
var id = stuff[stuff.length-1];
//id = 234234234
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const url = "http://www.example.com/1234"
const id = url.split('/').pop();
```

Try this, it is much easier

The output gives 1234

Answer (score 5):

You could just use `window.location.hash` to grab the id.

```
var id = window.location.hash;
```

I don't think you will need that much code to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

try this javascript

Snippet for getting the parameters from URL. Use javascript to get the URL parameters either from current window location or static URL into the argument for the function call.

**javascript**

```
function getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode){

       var currLocation = (staticURL.length)? staticURL : window.location.search,
           parArr = currLocation.split("?")[1].split("&"),
           returnBool = true;

       for(var i = 0; i < parArr.length; i++){
            parr = parArr[i].split("=");
            if(parr[0] == parameter){
                return (decode) ? decodeURIComponent(parr[1]) : parr[1];
                returnBool = true;
            }else{
                returnBool = false;            
            }
       }

       if(!returnBool) return false;  
    }
```

To get the parameter “id” from above static URL, use the following:

```
var idParameter = getUrlParameters("id", "http://www.example.com?id=1234&auth=true", true);
```

**or**

```
var idParameter = getUrlParameters("id", "", true);
```

Comment: Very useful.. Thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

My url is like this http://www.default-search.net/?sid=503 . I want to get 503 . I wrote the following code .

```
var baseUrl = (window.location).href; // You can also use document.URL
var koopId = baseUrl.substring(baseUrl.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
alert(koopId)//503
```

If you use

```
var v = window.location.pathname;
console.log(v)
```

You will get only "/";

Comment: this didn't work for me, but Rohrbs post above worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [jQuery URL Parser plugin](http://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser), you should be able to do this:

```
jQuery.url.segment(1)
```

Comment: I like this one because most other of the proposed solutions seem to fail when there are anchors, query parameters, ... involved.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I can:

```
function pathName(url, a) {
   return (a = document.createElement('a'), a.href = url, a.pathname); //optionally, remove leading '/'
}

pathName("http://www.site.com/234234234") -> "/234234234"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option using the built-in [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) which worth it when one has more URL specific work to do besides string extraction.

> The URL interface is used to parse, construct, normalize, and encode URLs. It works by providing properties which allow you to easily read and modify the components of a URL.

```js
const url = new URL('http://www.foo.bar/234234234');
alert(url.pathname.slice(1)); // 234234234
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var url = "http://www.exmple.com/234234234"
var res = url.split("/").pop();
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

this would cover all possible cases.

```
window.location.href.split("/").pop().split("?")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the solution @BalusC provided will work for the question's context. But if the url contains some query params like the one below it will not work.

```
http://www.example.com/234234234?limit=10&sort=desc
```

In this scenario you can use the following:

```js
const url = "http://www.example.com/234234234?limit=10&sort=desc"

const id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.indexOf("?"));
```

Now `id` will contain only the id number `234234234`.

Hope this helps.