# dynamically generate content for a page when clicking on product

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

everyone. I am making a website with t-shirts. I dynamically generate preview cards for products using a JSON file but I also need to generate content for an HTML file when clicking on the card. So, when I click on it, a new HTML page opens like  `product.html?product_id=id`. I do not understand how to check for id or this part `?prodcut_id=id`, and based on id it generates content for the page. Can anyone please link some guides or good solutions, I don't understand anything :(.

Comment: You need code that runs server-side and does the lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the user's browser to ask the server to load a particular page based on the value of a variable called `product_id`.

The way a browser talks to a server is an **HTTP Request**, about which you can learn all the basics on [javascipt.info](https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest) and/or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

The `?product_id=id` is called the 'query' part of the **URL**, about which you can learn more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

A request that gets a page with this kind of URL from the server is usually **a `GET` request**, which is simpler and requires less security than the more common and versatile `POST` request type.

You may notice some of the resources talking about `AJAX` requests (which are used to update *part* of the current page without reloading the whole thing), but you won't need to worry about this since you're just trying to have the browser navigate to a new page.

**Your server needs to have some code to handle any such requests**, basically saying:

"If anybody sends an HTTP GET request here, look at the value of the `product_id` variable and compare it to my available HTML files. If there's a match, send a response with the matching file, and if there's no match, send a page that says 'Error 404'."

That's the quick overview anyway. The resources will tell you much more about the details.

Answer (score 2):

There are some solutions, how you can get the parameters from the url:
[Get ID from URL with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730359/get-id-from-url-with-jquery)

It would also makes sense to understand what is a REST Api and how to build a own one, because i think you dont have a backend at the moment.
Here some refs:
https://www.conceptatech.com/blog/difference-front-end-back-end-development
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm